# Need a Data Sctructure of set size that behaves like a queue... but I'm not sure if I can/should use a queue here

Tags: python, data-structures

I need a data structure that has n slots. Each slot receives an item. When a new item is added the oldest item is automatically removed.The items themselves have some properties, like name, age, size, height, etc. I need to be able to do some computation on the properties of the items that are in the queue/list. The items themselves could be objects or dictionaries or just lists or tuples. For example, let's say we have a queue of 15 individuals and I need to know the maximum age of a member of the queue. Or the average height of the last 10 members. What would be the best data structure to use here? I'm not sure what would be the best way to arrange this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Edit: The easiest solution I've come up with is to use a data frame. When a new individual needs to be added, add a row with all the necessary information and drop the first row of the data frame. This is probably not efficient if there is a lot of data but it makes computation on the existing elements very straight-forward.

Comment: It sounds like a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) would work here.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I will try it... but how would I get the average height/size/etc of the last 10 people in the deque... this is what I'm really struggling with. Each of my individuals are an object, I anticipate this is part of the problem, though I'm not sure how I would go about it if each was a dict or list... any tips or links would be highly appreciated

Comment: deques are nice because it's easy to create a fixed size. But slicing them is a little less convenient. `itertools.islice` is handy for this though. For example, given a deque `dq` with dicts that have an age property you can find the sum of the last three ages with something like `sum(d['age'] for d in islice(dq, len(d) - 3, len(d)))` Not as convenient as a list, but maybe worth if for the fixed-length.

Comment: @MarkMeyer the best solutions I've been able to come up with is using a data frame and manually deleting rows off the end (but the slicing is straight forward)... I'm thinking it's really inefficient. I will definitely look at itertools.islice... i wasn't able to find anything on slicing deques so I was about to give up on them! thank you